# Replacing only 3rd to 6th position of a String

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to SQL. I want to replace only 3rd to 6th(only 1st 1234) position of below string with '1219', but its replacing whole new string:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE('DD123412341234',SUBSTR('DD123412341234',3,4),'1219' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Kindle suggest on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with function [regexp_replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490).

```sql
select regexp_replace('DD123412341234','....','1219',3,1) as RESULT from DUAL
```

As stated in the documentation, the second function parameter is the regular expression to search for which, in this case, is any four characters. The third parameter is the replacement string. The fourth [optional] parameter indicates to start the search from the third character and the final [also optional] parameter means only search for the first occurrence and replace that first occurrence with `1219`.

The result of the above query is `DD121912341234`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. its working with regexp_replace. bt having issue with performance as record count is huge. Is it possible to update the first occurrence with replace only without using regexp_replace.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions tend to be relatively slow. Since you know the specific location to replace an alternative would be sub the parts to be kept and rebuild with the concatenation operator. The following **may** be faster, but it does involve more operations.

```
with test(t) as 
     (select 'DD123412341234' from dual) 
select substr(t,1,2) || '1219' || substr(t,7) 
   from test;
```